# CSS: Hide repeat class in different div

Tags: css

```
<div>
    <div class="A_class">A</div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="A_class">A</div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="A_class">A</div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="A_class">A</div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="B_class">B</div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="B_class">B</div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="B_class">B</div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="C_class">C</div>
</div>
```

RESULT:

```
A
A
A
A
B
B
B
C
```

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
A
B
C
```

Hi Guys, based on the code above, how can I display the expected result by using css only. Javascript and jQuery are not allow to use in this case.

**Add On**
I'm very sorry didn't mention HTML part. The HTML part is dynamically generated.

Comment: This cannot be achieved in css alone, at least not as of now. If the `:has` selector is implemented by browsers then this can be achieved only using css https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

Comment: @z0mBi3 Oh I see. Thanks for your information. I though is had a way to solve this problem by using CSS only but based on what you say, I think I need to solve this problem by using another method.

Comment: @z0mBi3 this can be achieve using css I have answer for this question please check I have added the working fidler also..

Comment: @ShakirAhamed if the html is static you can do this. But if the html is generated dynamically you might need to add those A_Show using javascript or in the place where elements are generated. As per the HTML provided in the question this cannot be achieved in css alone without altering the html or using javascript.

Comment: @z0mBi3 yeah you wright but he didn't mentioned it's generating dynamically write

Answer (score 0):

Try this
you have to keep a different class name to one div in repeating div like below

```css
.A_class{
    display: none;
 }
 .A_Show .A_class{
    display: block;
 }

    
.B_class{
   display: none;
 }
    .B_show .B_class{
     display: block;
 }
    
 .C_class{
    display: none;
  }
  .C_show .C_class{
     display: block;
 }
```

```html
<div class="A_Show">
    <div class="A_class">A</div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="A_class">A</div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="A_class">A</div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="A_class">A</div>
</div>

<div class="B_show">
    <div class="B_class">B</div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="B_class">B</div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="B_class">B</div>
</div>

<div class="C_show">
    <div class="C_class">C</div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="C_class">C</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.whole-wrap div:first-child .A_class,
 .whole-wrap div:first-child .B_class,
 .whole-wrap div:first-child .C_class {
  display: block;
 }
 .A_class,
 .B_class,
 .C_class {
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="whole-wrap">   
    <div>
    <div class="A_class">A</div>
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <div class="A_class">A</div>
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <div class="A_class">A</div>
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <div class="A_class">A</div>
    </div>
</div>    

<div class="whole-wrap">  
    <div>
        <div class="B_class">B</div>
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <div class="B_class">B</div>
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <div class="B_class">B</div>
    </div>
 </div>   
    
<div class="whole-wrap"> 
    <div>
        <div class="C_class">C</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be achieved in css alone, at least not as of now. But we can achieve your output. here is one simple example

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media screen{
        .A_class * {visibility: visible;}
        .A_class{ position: absolute; }
        .B_class * {visibility: visible;}
        .B_class{ position: absolute; margin-top: 20px;}
        .C_class * {visibility: visible;}
        .C_class{ position: absolute; margin-top: 40px;}
    }
</style>
```